# Typescript no error on generic type mismatch

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm attempting to build a type safe attachment system, but typescript doesn't seem to throw an error when the types mismatch in a generic function call

```
// Generic key that holds value type info
type GenericTypeMarker<T> = string;

// Standard dictionarny
const dictionary: { [id: string]: any } = {};

// Put item into dict with type specified by key
function putItem<T>(key: GenericTypeMarker<T>, item: T) {
    dictionary[key] = item;
}

// Get item from dict with type specified by key
function getItem<T>(key: GenericTypeMarker<T>): T {
    return dictionary[key];
}


// A test key with type of number
const TestKey: GenericTypeMarker<number> = "testKey";

// type mismatch between value and key, but no error
putItem(TestKey, "not a string");
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Generic%20key%20that%20holds%20value%20type%20info%0D%0Atype%20GenericTypeMarker%3CT%3E%20%3D%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Standard%20dictionarny%0D%0Aconst%20dictionary%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Put%20item%20into%20dict%20with%20type%20specified%20by%20key%0D%0Afunction%20putItem%3CT%3E(key%3A%20GenericTypeMarker%3CT%3E%2C%20item%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dictionary%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20item%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Get%20item%20from%20dict%20with%20type%20specified%20by%20key%0D%0Afunction%20getItem%3CT%3E(key%3A%20GenericTypeMarker%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20dictionary%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20A%20test%20key%20with%20type%20of%20number%0D%0Aconst%20TestKey%3A%20GenericTypeMarker%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%22testKey%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20mismatch%20between%20value%20and%20key%2C%20but%20no%20error%0D%0AputItem(TestKey%2C%20%22not%20a%20string%22)%3B%0D%0A)

I don't see why the last line doesn't throw a compiler error when the type of the key and value don't line up.

EDIT: per jcalz comment, I understand why this is the case. However, is there a way around this that maintains type safety?

Comment: See [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your generic type `GenericTypeMarker` doesn't use the type parameter `T`. As of TypeScript 2.8, the compiler can flag that as [an error](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#unused-type-parameters-are-checked-under---nounusedparameters).

What you want is called [literal types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/) in Flow. There have been [requests](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) to add it to TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned if you don't use the type parameter it has little effect on compatibility, so the simplest solution is to use it. The most benign way to use it is to intersect `string` with a type that contains a dummy property, (similar to branded types)

```
// Generic key that holds value type info
type GenericTypeMarker<T> = string & { markerHelper: T };

// Standard dictionarny
const dictionary: { [id: string]: any } = {};

// Put item into dict with type specified by key
function putItem<T>(key: GenericTypeMarker<T>, item: T) {
    dictionary[key] = item;
}

function makeMarker<T>(value : string) : GenericTypeMarker<T>{
  return value as any
}
// create the key with an any assertion 
const TestKey: GenericTypeMarker<number> = "testKey" as any;
// or using the helper
const TestKey2 =  makeMarker<number>("testKey");

putItem(TestKey,2); // ok
putItem(TestKey,"2");// error
```

The disadvantage is someone might try to access `TestKey.marker` and be surprised that there is no value. One workaround is to use `T & never` for the `marker` type  which although when you try to access `marker`evaluates to `never` still works for the purpose of infering `T` in `putItems` for example:

```
type GenericTypeMarker<T> = string & { marker: T & never};

const TestKey =  makeMarker<number>("testKey");
let d = TestKey.marker; // d is never
putItem(TestKey,2); // ok
putItem(TestKey,"2");// error
```

Comment: @jcalz I can't believe keep  mixed them up again, 10x :)